# Lightning controller gets no response from class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller

i am having the worst time, and i need some help

i have the following code in lightning

component

```
<aura:attribute name="usersList" type="List"/><!--List Of User(s)-->    
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getResponse}"/>
```

class

```
public static List<User> getUserList(Id userId) {

    List<User> userList = [Select Id, Name, Constituent_ID__c, NetID__c from User where Id=:userId];
    return userList;
}       

}
```

controller

```
({
    getResponse : function(component) {
        //doesnt exist here console.log(component.get("v.recordId")+ " portfolio link");
        var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
        console.log(userId);
        var action = component.get("c.getUserList");

        action.setParams({
            userId: $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")
        });        

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) { 
            console.log('got this far');
        if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS") { 
            component.set("v.usersList", response.getReturnValue()); 
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
        }}); 


        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

I get the console.log for the userId in the controller, but then it just stops, not moving forward on the get callback

the lightning component just never shows up, not sure what the deal is, the query is sound, the current user id is good, everything looks good

sigh any help is appreciated

Comment: are you sure you are calling the right method? in your action, you seem to be calling getUserList, however, your method name in the apex controller is returnUser ?

Comment: @glls yea i copied the class wrong, its correct now, sorry been a long day

Comment: hehe, no worries, happens to everyone =P

Comment: Is the controller attribute defined on the `aura:component` (if so, is it marked `@AuraEnabled`)? If the `console.log` is the last line that fires, that would lead me to believe you're getting an error that it couldn't retrieve the method `c.getUserList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was for some dumb reason, the class must have ben name spaced wrong is my only guess, but i startd from scratch same code, differnent names, and it worked great

Who knows right?

Answer (score 1):

So I tried working with your code in my org. I found that the code when used directly, gave me the below error.

> Unknown controller action 'getUserList'

Then I tried changing a few things and came to a working page where the user list got printed inside `console`.

So while setting the params for the method, I used `userId` variable directly instead of setting it using `$A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")`.

So below is the working code for me.

```
getResponse : function(component) {
        //doesnt exist here console.log(component.get("v.recordId")+ " portfolio link");
        var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
        console.log(userId);
        var action = component.get("c.getUserList");

        action.setParams({
            userId: userId //Changed here
        });        

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) { 
            console.log('got this far');
        if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS") { 
            component.set("v.usersList", response.getReturnValue()); 
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
        }}); 


        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

**No sure why it is not assigning the value using `$A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")` . May be someone else can shed some light on it.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wncoutered the same and made the same edit, so idea why it cant assign that to a var